# BadMethodCallException executing laravel artisan migrate

Tags: php, database, laravel

When I type "php artisan migrate", it gives the following error:

> BadMethodCallException  : Method
>   Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::password does not exist.
>
> at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\laravellab1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable.php:98
>   94|      */  95|     public function __call($method, $parameters)  96|
>   {  97|         if (! static::hasMacro($method)) {
>
> > 98|             throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(  99|                 'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method 100|
> >     )); 101|         } 102|

Comment: Show the file with your migration.

Comment: And please fix your title while you're at it. Something that concisely summarizes the problem would be good. See [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your migration has `$table->password()` in it I expect - change this to `$table->string()`

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem, it was a silly mistake.

Comment: I believe this question and the answer is very useful. Specially in the cases where you are coding with a text editor and the error log or stack traces flood you with loads of unnecessary information that is hiding the actual problem. When you stumble upon such, you can simply Google and trace the problem.